# I plagiarised using chatGPT in my thesis, I assume I will be caught and maybe expelled. How do I create a more lenient punishment?

Tags: thesis, university, plagiarism, generative-ai

Of course, the no-brainer is using chatGPT. I have done something atrocious and unjustified. I realize that I have made a massive mistake after handing in my own assignment. I wrote a thesis with one section from chatGPT copy-paste (the dumbest). In a few days, my thesis will be analyzed through Turnitin by my supervisor, and I already feel a plagiarism accusation coming. Understandably, I should be punished for my wrongdoings. I just hope my university does not punish me too hard for plagiarism. Under the board of examiners there are multiple penalties regarding a reprimand, a void grade (NG or fail) in the assignment, suspension for the upcoming period (so a one-year delay), or the worst (getting expelled).
Obviously, I cannot deny my act, and I will take full responsibility. I just want to learn from my wrongdoings and hope to obtain a second chance.  I have no control over the verdict of the board. I just want to learn from this action and plead for a more lenient sentence.
Does anyone have tips or guidance on what to do?

*edit* when worse comes to worst, I will consider asking a lawyer to aid me

Comment: Well, you have the following choice to make, I guess: (a) tell them in advance that you made the mistake to use ChatGPT in one section without correctly marking that you used this tool, or (b) wait until they find out. Whether (a) is favourable over (b) depends on the way your school works. From an academic integrity point of view, (a) is the way to go, but whether it's the smartest thing to do for you personally for reducing punishment (in the worst case or the mean expected punishment) is incredible hard to tell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I preemptively confess after submitting work that was partially generated by ChatGPT?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/196712/should-i-preemptively-confess-after-submitting-work-that-was-partially-generated)

Comment: @DCTLib "(b) depends on the way your school works" - Therefore, there is a students' union at OP's school, OP will probably do better to consult them rather than this forum.

Comment: Would someone care to explain to me how using ChatGPT differs from requesting the services of a professional editor?

Comment: The difference is irrelevant. The question clearly states the user copy-pasted text from another source into their thesis, without attribution. This is plagiarism, academic dishonesty, and will rightfully earn a zero grade on the thesis, at the very minimum. @DennisFrancisBlewett

Answer (score 12):

This is the basic problem: the minute that there is a predictable way to avoid punishment, the deterrent effect of the punishment disappears. So there is not, and should not be, an obvious, easy and predictable way to avoid punishment.

You have two obvious choices: to 'fess up and hope for a lesser punishment, or to wait and see if they actually catch you. From the perspective of those of us who administer punishment to students who cheat, we are always inclined to be less severe with those who confess. Part of this is that by encouraging confessions, we hope to not create an environment where it's always to students' advantage to wait and see if they are caught. But if, again, it becomes predicable that we will be very lenient with those that confess, then what we encourage is cheating followed by confession with increased expectations of leniency. And maximum leniency is no disciplinary action, and that just brings us back to the basic problem of deterrence. The comparison group is not those that did not confess, but those who did not cheat. Are we being fair to those who did the work themselves? That's the question.

You mention that you are really sorry, and that you just want to learn from your lesson. The problem is that you are likely lying to yourself, not on purpose, but still. Let me assure you that 100% of the time I am lenient to a cheating student, they do it again, only that this time they assure me that they are not 100% sure, but 1,000% sure they'll never to it again. We don't want to punish students, we want them to stop cheating. Thus, the only way to reach our true goal is to administer a punishment that "hurts." Hurts in the sense that it creates enough discomfort and regret, that it prevents the act form happening again.

If you really want to stop yourself from doing this again, then confess and accept whatever disciplinary action they take against you. It has the added benefit that it might bring, albeit not guarantee, leniency.

Last, try to keep a balance between feeling bad for what you did, and overdoing the self-recrimination. Cheating is academia is rampant and widespread. Before LMLs came about, it was Chegg, and before Chegg, it was paying Internet "tutors" to do the work for you, and so on. Only the technology has made it easier to cheat, but I really doubt that students in the 80s where less inclined to cheat: they just didn't have the technology, or were never caught (look at how many theses from famous people are being found to be plagiarized now that automatic tools are available.) There's plenty of guilt to go around: from professors who never check for plagiarism or just test for things that can be answered with a quick Google search, to ever-lenient administrators never wanting to "punish" a paying customer, to a general devaluation from students about what constitutes an education. We are trying to *train* you here, so please, do the training exercises. Like I ask my students caught cheating: Do you also pay someone to go to the gym for you?

Comment: "the minute that there is a predictable way to avoid punishment, the deterrent effect of the punishment disappears" - this! +1

Comment: worthwhile changing the question title to a more general question about how plagiarism instead of avoiding punishment perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Now is the time for damage control as soon as possible.

If possible, withdraw your assignment immediately.  Naturally, this will result in not getting a grade, because you will have missed the assignment deadline.  This is very likely less bad than the penalty for plagiarism or cheating.