Ethical arguments against cheating on an exam when everyone else is cheating and the class is curved?
Let's start with an extreme thought experiment. The professor announces there is an online, unproctored exam. Let's assume everyone in the class is cheating on an exam except for you. And you know that there is a zero percent chance that there will be consequences for any of them, as the course staff are irresponsible. You know that the professor won't do anything even if you reach out to them or higher-ups. You need to do well on the class in order to get a job to fund your aging parents' healthcare. The class is curved, so your classmates doing better makes you do worse in comparison and jeopardizes your chances at receiving this job. Should one be allowed to cheat in this situation?
I'm interested in the ethical arguments in particular. Two arguments out of the scope of this discussion are the potential consequences of getting caught (let's assume there are none here), and the potential impact of your long-term decision making (let's assume there are no future decisions of such importance).
I believe we can frame this problem as a prisoner dilemma set-up, where the other parties (i.e the classmates) are defecting - if everyone cheats, they are all worse off since they learned less. But if you don't cheat here, then you are worse off individually due to the class being curved and the reality that everyone else is cheating.
I am interested in the implications here for real-life situations. We can modify some parameters of the thought experiment depending on the environment. In environments that I'm familiar with, the chance that cheaters get caught are non-zero, but very low. The proportion of cheaters can range up to even 50% or higher in competitive/toxic departments, especially during COVID.
Why is it unethical for a student to cheat here, when the alternative would be at their own expense?

What do you even consider cheating in this case? We had exams in which you were literally allowed to bring as much material as you could carry, including all learning material and practice sheets/exams. The exam was setup like this on purpose because "cheating" wouldn’t give any advantage over just being good enough to write down the answer.

I downvoted ... but NOT because I consider discussions about cheating without remorse to be out of bounds (see  https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/196909/104266 ). Rather, I downvoted you because I think your question is poorly constructed and attempts (with a modicum of success) to force the reader into a particular response. As a result, responses are unlikely to be able to engage properly with issues such as the variety of descriptions/definitions of ethical behaviour, utilitarianism, etc.

Or, perhaps, you learn the material well enough that you don't have any need to cheat?

The mental gymnastics and scheming I have seen my students put themselves through during the virtual experiment during and immediately post Covid was hilarious. When in reality just learning the course material, and using the provided resources would have taken less time/effort. Unrelated to your question, but those students are now matriculating to graduate school and they are the most clueless/helpless cohort I have ever had to deal with.

I do not intend to force the reader to a particular response. This is the framework in which I'm thinking about the problem, and I genuinely do not understand why it would be unethical for a student to be cheat in this case. That is why I am asking the question, and the question has been downvoted yet no one has given a genuine reply.

@9j09jf02jsd I am still waiting for clarification on my comment. The situation described is incredibly vague and right now requires answerers to fill in the blanks by guessing.

Your question feels equivalent to "if a person is subjected to a "highly unjust" (whatever that means) system of rules, is it unethical to disobey those rules?". This question is a famous classical philosophical question which I'm not interested in answering because there's a whole other stackexchange for that sort of thing.
When we realize that we have subjected our students to a highly unjust system of rules[1], whether or not individual actors choose to follow our unjust system of rules or not should become irrelevant. Instead, the sole focus of our energies should be on addressing the inequities of that system of rules.
[1] Where by "rules" I mean the rules of the exam, the grading, how it is monitored, how breaking the rules is not incentivized, and how these rules are enforced.

Interesting points, though I think the premise of the question is that OP is a student who does not have control over the professor's actions.

If everyone is cheating and there is very little chance of being caught, one would think why not cheat?
However, what would I really have learnt due to cheatong?
My goal would be to learn whether I fail because I didn't cheat. At least I learnt something. Rather than learning nothing in order to pass with the cool group.

I don’t see why cheating and learning would be  at odds. There are also veritable downsides to failing an exam that go well beyond having one’s knowledge checked. Can you perhaps clarify why you consider cheating versus learning to be a strict choice?

I tend to agree with you there after a period of thought. You could still learn even of you cheated. I have done plenty of of examinations that were open book. You just needed to know where to look for the answers. I supposed if you cheated, no one could say you were not learning. I can't say that cheating versus learning to be a strict choice no longer. Perhaps the end does justify the means. It depends on your objective. I have taken short cuts before, however I had to learn retrospectively. I achieved my objective of getting passed a stage.
